# language don't change in landscape mode android java

Tags: java, android

i am having hard time in this do not know why this is happening

my android manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

now when i load my MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        orienta(this);

        setLanguage(this, getLanguage(this, "en"));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
```

now these function of orientation and language code are as follows

```
    public void orienta(Context c){
            SharedPreferences spp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
            String ss = spp.getString("orientation", "portrait");

            if (ss.equals("portrait")) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            if (ss.equals("landscape")) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        }

private String getLanguage(Context c, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        return preferences.getString("language", defaultLanguage);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void setLanguage(Context context, String languageCode) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);


        // Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            config.locale = locale;
        }
        context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("language", languageCode);
        editor.apply();

    }
```

now the problem is that
in portrait mode every activity shows the language which is selected in settings

but in landscape mode the language is only shown in fragment and navigation menu items,
in preferenceactivty and other activities and also in toolbar it is same english language how to fix it

i have added

```
android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in each and every activity defined in manifest

**EDIT :-
by putting in every activity before setcontentview make landscape mode works
don't know why this issue is coming
if anybody get this issue in future and fixed it please comment
only coming in landscape mode**

Comment: what u want to achieve??

Comment: i want to keep language user selected in settings (ie preferenceactivity) in both orientation ,on portrait in all activities the langauge is same what user selects but in landscaoe language changes to english on some texts ,except the fragment loads in start get the language selected in settings in landscape mode else everywhere is english

Answer (score 1):

well by putting setlanguage method call in every activity fix issue on landscape mode ,well portrait mode works fine just calling it in mainactivity but to make language works in landscape mode it needs to call in every activity

in future is someone get this issue or have fix please comment